# Document plotting using Pyplot and sklearn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am looking to gain insight into the layout of my document set. 
I am casting them to a numbers array using the following approach from SKlearn.

```
  pipeline = Pipeline([("vect", CountVectorizer()), 
                      ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),])

  matrix = pipeline.fit_transform(docs).todense()
```

If I were to cluster them I would use

```
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(matrix)
    data2D = kmeans.transform(matrix)
```

Then I would plot them using pyplot

```
    plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c = categories)
```

However, this generates a kmeans representation of the dataset. Is there anyway of summing up the values in the Matrix and plotting them as they are so I can see how they are relative to each other, without using kmeans. So that my representation is consistent eveytime.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are coming after me. The principle in question is known as Multidimensional Scaling. Here is a useful blog that explains the principles behind it. https://de.dariah.eu/tatom/working_with_text.html